# Xamarin form methods wont process

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am creating a mobile application in visual studio using Xamarin forms. For my honors project at university. I am trying to read a message from an ardunio nfc shield to my mobile application that I have created. But when I try to process the message the piece of code gets skipped over.

My code is as following:

```
if (nfcadapter.ndefdiscovered == intent.action)
```

`processIntent(Intent)` skips this part.

I have put a `console.writeline` in before it to see if it matches and it doesn't match the `intent.action` says `intent.action.main`.

I have tried `nfcadapter.ndefdiscovered`, tagdiscoverd and techdiscovered then all don't work.

Comment: Please show us more of the code!

Comment: Did you try debug through the code.

Comment: This is expected behavior, if the code you provided is complete. Your if conditional doesnt evaluate to true, `nfcadapter.ndefdiscovered` does not equal `intent.action`, so the next line is skipped. If it should equal that, you need to go farther back in the code to find out why it doesnt.